# What's the correct syntax for calling the body css class in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my `application.html.erb` I set the css class of the body to the current controller and action:

`<body class="<%= controller_name %> <%= action_name %>">`

Now I want to display a certain link on a page depending on the value of the body class. How do I call the body class in the following if else statement?

```
<% if ?body_class? == 'index' %>

<%= link_to 'This link', '#' %>

<% else %>

<%= link_to 'That link', '#' %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you output the body tag, you're not assigning any variables, so you can't refer to it later as "body_class". Since your body class is simply the controller + action, you could do the following:

```
<% if params[:controller] == 'foo' and params[:action] == 'index' %>
```

Or if you're in foo controller then just params[:action]. Alternatively have a before_filter on your application that does something like:

```
@body_classes = [params[:controller], params[:action]]
```

And then a helper:

```
def body_classes
  @body_classes.join(' ')
end

def body_has_class?(name)
  @body_classes.include?(name)
end
```

And then in your layout:

```
<body class="<%= body_classes %>">
<% if body_has_class?('index') %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `action_name`, like you did before:

```
<%= link_to (action_name == 'index' ? 'This link' : 'That link'), '#' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in [link_to_if](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to_if) helper as well as [current_page](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-current_page-3F)

```
link_to_if (current_page?(action: "index), "This Path", this_path ) do
  link_to "That path", that_path
end
```

Will produce

```
# If current action is index
<a href="/this/path">This path</a>

# Else
<a href="/that/path">That path</a>
```